# How to fix "Cannot directly backTransform an unmarkedEstimate with length > 1" error in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, predict, unmarked-package

I'm trying to make a line plot of the relationship of density on the real scale, based on estimates from the model (hn.l.s). But I'm stuck on Back-transforming it to real scale. Am I right in backtransforming or should I have gone straight to plot()?

I've tried backTransform(hn.l.s, type="state") instead of "det" but neither works.

```
dist<-seq(0,60,15)
obs<-as.matrix(dat[,1:4])
site_covs<-data.frame(shrub=dat[,c("d.shrub")],light=dat[,c("light")])
umf<-unmarkedFrameDS(y=obs,siteCovs=site_covs,dist.breaks=c(dist),survey="point",unitsIn="m")
hn.1.s<-distsamp(~1~shrub,umf,keyfun="halfnorm",output="density",unitsOut="ha")
pred.hn.l.s<-predict(hn.l.s,"state",se.fit=TRUE)
backTransform(hn.l.s, type="det")
```

> Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
>     Cannot directly backTransform an unmarkedEstimate with length > 1.

I was expecting to get a detection estimate from:

```
backTransform(hn.l.s, type="det")
```

Which would have given me a number:

```
sigma<-[the number]
```

Then I would have estimated the half-normal exp:

```
hn.l.s@estimates
```

And gotten:

```
b<-exp([a diff number])
```

Then calculated:

```
p.hn.l.s<-1-exp(-(dist/sigma)^-b)
```

And gotten a plot with:

```
plot(dist,p.hn.l.s,type="l",xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,1), xlab="Distance", ylab="Detection probability")
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example, I can't give you a precise answer, but basically, you can only use `backTransform` when there are no covariates. If there ARE covariates, then you need to specify the covariate values at which to make the back transformation. You can do that using the `linearComb` function (see the unmarked manual [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unmarked/unmarked.pdf#Rfn.linearComb.Rdash.methods.1)). You can then use `backTransform` on the results of the `linearComb` function.